# How to get newly inserted row ids when inserting with execute?

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, postgresql-10

I have a function which returns newly inserted row count:

```
   BEGIN
   EXECUTE (

      SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s) SELECT %2$s FROM %1$s WHERE budget_id = $1',
                    _tbl, string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', '))
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
      AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
      AND    attname <> 'id'   -- exclude id column

      )
   USING _id;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- directly assign OUT parameter
  END;
```

Instead, I have to return a list which contains newly inserted row ids. How can I do that?

I tried with `result_oid,@@identity` but I got no result.
This function is returning only one value. How can I get all the values?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test2(_tbl regclass,_id integer)
RETURNS integer[]
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100
AS $BODY$DECLARE 
ab integer;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE (

  SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s) SELECT %2$s FROM %1$s WHERE budget_id = $1 RETURNING id',
                _tbl, string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', '))
  FROM   pg_attribute
  WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
  AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
  AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
  AND    attname <> 'id'   -- exclude id column
  )
 USING _id 
 into ab;

 RETURN ARRAY[ab];
END;$BODY$;
```

Comment: Try the `RETURNING` clause of `INSERT`.

Comment: can you please give me example ?? I tried with 
('INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s) SELECT %2$s FROM %1$s WHERE budget_id = $1 RETURNING id)  
SELECT array_agg(id) INTO abcd FROM ins'

but didn't get any result.

Comment: When you write `I have to return a list`, do you mean an *array*, a *set* or an actual (comma-separated) *list*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes i mean an array

Comment: I added an array variant.

Comment: thanks @ErwinBrandstetter , your answer solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a ***set***, Use [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) in a function that [`RETURNS SETOF integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pubilc.test_set(_tbl regclass, _id int)
  RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   WITH (
   SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s)
                  SELECT %2$s FROM %1$s WHERE budget_id = $1
                  RETURNING id'
                , _tbl, string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', '))
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
   AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
   AND    attname <> 'id'   -- exclude id from column list
   )
   USING _id;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;  -- don't quote the language name
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM pubilc.test_set('mytbl', 123);
```

To return an ***array***, move the `INSERT` to a CTE and feed the result to an array constructor.

Then we don't need the function to `RETURNS SETOF int[]`, because it always returns a single value. The simplest way is to define an `OUT` parameter and assign the result of the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_arr(_tbl regclass, _id int, OUT _ids int[]) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('WITH ids AS (
                     INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s)
                     SELECT %2$s FROM %1$s WHERE budget_id = $1
                     RETURNING id
                     )
                  SELECT ARRAY (TABLE ids)'
               , _tbl, string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', '))
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
   AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
   AND    attname <> 'id'   -- exclude id from column list
   )
   USING _id
   INTO _ids;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT public.test_arr('mytbl', 123);
```

Related:

- [RETURN value directly from INSERT with RETURNING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148876/return-value-directly-from-insert-with-returning-clause/148970#148970)
- [Find changed columns for near-identical rows across tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129265/find-changed-columns-for-near-identical-rows-across-tables/129385#129385)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)